# Multiple construct functions

Tags: php, oop, methods, laravel

I'm trying to initizalize a couple of helper classes into my laravel controller only problem is I have 3 things to initialize but only one constructor message for exmaple:

```
<?php
use UG\Validation\Forms\Login as LoginForm;

class SessionsController extends \BaseController {

protected $loginForm;

public function __construct(LoginForm $loginForm)
{
    $this->loginForm = $loginForm;
}
```

That is to help validate the forms but now I also want to add a repository to help me with keeping eloquent out of my controller

```
<?php
use UG\Repositories\User as User;

class SessionsController extends \BaseController {

protected $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

now the problem Im facing is that both these methods need to go in my controller but I only have one _construct method. So how would I go about this

Comment: why can't you just put both in the constructor?

Comment: BTW, you need to call the `parent::__construct()` inside each of your `__construct()` so that the `BaseController`'s construct is also called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put both classes in the constructor:

```
class SessionsController extends \BaseController {

protected $user;
protected $loginForm;

public function __construct(User $user, LoginForm $loginForm)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->loginForm = $loginForm;
}
```